# PHP - Using filter_input, isset and other

Tags: php, isset, filter-input

I just want to ask. I noticed that Netbeans is shouting on me to use filter_input(). So I used it but I dont really understand it. Lets say I have this code

```
if(isset($_POST['button'])){}
```

what is diffent when I use

```
if (filter_input(INPUT_POST,'button')){}
```

Also when I am using some posts to get values

```
$header = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'header',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Normaly I use this

```
$header = $_POST['header']
```

What are rules to using it, what does it doing ? When to use it. And use it with POST or GET or both ?
Because code is bigger with it, and I personally like small code I can use whenever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases this can abuse for MySQL injection or code injection.

```
 $var = $_POST["ANYVALUE"]
```

To Avoid this, we use filter_input to replace some dangerous Characters.
Or Simple u can check for right E-Mail Adresse.

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, var, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

If you send password value use only POST method. The GET method is Visible on the Browsers URL. So if you use GET u need have more work to do.

A list of different filters and description you find here: [PHP: Types of filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php)

So filters are great for validation!

Small description:
All what the user can type in your system must by checked for the right value to avoid hackers.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Np, can you mark my answer? Under The Vote Button's. Thanks :)